# Internationalization with Spring and JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, internationalization

I am facing trouble in JSP spring internationalization. My dispatcherServlet.xml contains:

```
   <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
<!-- Application Message Bundle -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages/messages" />
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
```

and my jsp contains

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Admin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href=<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout"/>>Logout</a><br/>



    Language : <a href="?language=en">English</a>|
    <a href="?language=zh_CN">Chinese</a>
 <h1>
        <spring:message code="only.Admin.allowed.here" text="default text" />
        </h1>    


    Current Locale : ${pageContext.response.locale}

    </body>
    </html>
```

The default EN language works fine, but I am not able to change the language into Chinese while clicking on Chinese option. The address bar URL changes to `/admin?language=en` to `/admin? language=zh_CN` but displays no result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a syntax error in you jsp:  the logout `href` does not have any `"`

Comment: Do you have a `messages_zh_CN.properties` file?

Comment: @Ralph - I suppose you are talking about the spring security logout tag (j_spring_security_logout), but it is working fine for us. And we have property file messages_zh_CN.properties in resource folder as per maven directory structure.

Comment: Does the chines properties file contain the message for `only.Admin.allowed.here`?

Comment: @Ralph - Yes, I think I got the problem, there is a welcome url mapping, if I used an index.jsp page and use sendRedirect("welcome") then it works, but I am not able to change that welcome mapping. Anyways Thanks..